# Performing regex Queries with in caluse with django and mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I have JSON objects for jobs where the job has a key call skills and the that is a list of skills. For example

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552a42cd03462b0728feb180"),
    "did" : "JB77FW6885MCCRGG30T",
    "attributes" : {
        "EducationRequired" : "Bachelor's Degree",
        "ExperienceRequired" : "At least 3 year(s)",
        "ExternalApplication" : "True",
        "City" : "Houston",
        "Company" : "IBM",
        "DegreeRequired" : "4 Year Degree",
        "Skills" : {
            "Skill" : [ 
                "apache hadoop", 
                "etl", 
                "geographic information system", 
                "cloud computing", 
                "mongodb", 
                "nosql", 
                "linux", 
                "spark (programming language)", 
                "java (programming language)", 
                "python (programming language)", 
                "sql", 
                "machine learning", 
                "data management", 
                "data integration"
            ]
        }
    }

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552a42cd03462b0728feb180"),
    "did" : "JB77FW6885MCCRGG30T",
    "attributes" : {
        "EducationRequired" : "Bachelor's Degree",
        "ExperienceRequired" : "At least 5 year(s)",
        "ExternalApplication" : "True",
        "City" : "Boston",
        "Company" : "Microsoft",
        "DegreeRequired" : "4 Year Degree",
        "Skills" : {
            "Skill" : [  
                "java (programming language)", 
                "python (programming language)", 
                "sql", 
                "machine learning", 
                "data management", 
                "data integration"
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

I want to get the jobs that has 'sql' or 'java'

I have the following call

```
skills = ['java','sql']
jobs = Job.objects(__raw__={'attributes.Skills.Skill' : {'$in' : skills}})
```

The issue with this is that it doesn't return the jobs that have 'java' because in the database the skills list has 'java (programming language)' and not just 'java'. In order to solve this, I need to put a regular expression in the query. So I tried the following but none of them worked:

```
Job.objects(__raw__={'attributes.Skills.Skill' : {'$in' : ['$/.*java.*/']}})  #ignoring sql for now
Job.objects(__raw__={'attributes.Skills.Skill' : {'$in' : ['sql',re.compile('$/.*java.*/', re.IGNORECASE)]}})
Job.objects(__raw__={'attributes.Skills.Skill' : {'$in' : ['sql',re.compile('/.*java.*/', re.IGNORECASE)]}})
```

Any ideas of what I should be doing?

Comment: Why not look directly for `java (programming language)`? Something like `skills = ['java (programming language)', 'sql']` ?

Comment: because there are other java (xxxxxx) instances in the data like java platform and so on. Usually candidates have Java on their skills, but the career builder API has java (programming language) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions

Your regular expressions are incorrect. Try these instead.

```
Job.objects(__raw__={'attributes.Skills.Skill' : {'$in' : [/.*java.*/i]}})  #ignoring sql for now
Job.objects(__raw__={'attributes.Skills.Skill' : {'$in' : ['sql',re.compile('.*java.*', re.IGNORECASE)]}})
```

Comment: That did it. The first one didn't work but the second one did. Thanks a lot